# Ways to solve the following equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand these solutions.

problem = $$ a^2 + ab - b = 0$$

$$a = \frac{-b + {\sqrt(b^2+4b)}}{2}$$
and
$$a = \frac{-b - {\sqrt(b^2+4b)}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These solutions arise from what is called the quadratic formula. The quadratic formula states: for any polynomial $$ax^2 + bx + c$$ the "roots" of this polynomial, in other words the values of x for which the polynomial evaluates to 0 can be found using the following formula: $$x = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$
This definition relates directly to your question only they have replaced x with a and the constants a, b and c are equal to 1, b and -b respectively.